# jQuery Change .CSS By Clicking A Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm kinda new to JS and jQuery. I've got an app that get's input from a user then prints it to the screen. I now want to add some jQuery to change the .CSS properties. Once the array is printed out to the screen, and the "Change my Look" link is clicked...I want to change the color to blue, and remove the "Change my Look" link. Nothing seems to be working now, and I'm kinda lost any help is much appreciated. Here is my HTML:

```
<h1 id='heading'></h1>        
<div id='grocery-list'>
    <ol class='items' id='list-items'>          
    </ol>
</div>
<a href='#list' id='change-look'>Change my Look</a>
   <div id='footer'>
    <p>
      &copy; Copyright  by Jake
    </p>
   </div>
```

And here is my js/jQuery

```
(document).ready(function() {           
        var groceries = getGroceries();
        printGroceries(groceries);
        $('#list').html('<h1>My Grocery List.</h1>');
        $('#change-look').click(fucntion() {
            $('#grocery-list').css('color','blue');
            $('h1').css('font-weight','bold','font-variant','small-caps','text-decoration','underline');
        };
        $('#change-look').not(this).find('a').removeAttr('href');

}
//var groceries = getGroceries();
//printGroceries(groceries);


function getGroceries() {

var canExit = false;
var myGroceries = new Array();
var grocery = null;
while (grocery != 'q') {

    grocery = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\’ to quit):", null);

    if ((grocery !== null) && (grocery != "q")) {
         myGroceries.push(grocery);
        canExit = true;
    }
}
return myGroceries;

}

function printGroceries(myGroceries) {

 if (myGroceries.length > 0) {
    //document.write("Here’s your grocery list:<br><br>" + myGroceries.join("<br><br>"));
    $('#list-items').html("<h1>My grocery list:</h1><br><br>" + myGroceries.join("<br><br>"));

    } else {//document.write("Sorry, your list is empty.");}
    $('#list-items').html("<p>Sorry, your list is empty</p>");}
}
```

Comment: My post cut off the bottom of my js code:

function printGroceries(myGroceries) {

    if (myGroceries.length > 0) {
        //document.write("Here’s your grocery list:<br><br>" + myGroceries.join("<br><br>"));
        $('#list-items').html("<h1>My grocery list:</h1><br><br>" + myGroceries.join("<br><br>"));

        } else {//document.write("Sorry, your list is empty.");}
        $('#list-items').html("<p>Sorry, your list is empty</p>");}
}

Comment: What do you want is not clear properly my friend , make a jsfiddle would be better !

Comment: I do use fiddle, but I'm not that understanding of it's suggestions. It tells me often that I'm missing semi-colons, but I almost always have then in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of sytanx issues/errors. One is already pointed out by Era. The ones is that you are not calling the ready function properly...

This...

```
(document).ready(function() {
```

must be changed to....

```
$(function(){
```

And also you are not closing the function calls properly. Replace your `jQuery` code with...

```
$(function() {           
        var groceries = getGroceries();
        printGroceries(groceries);
        $('#list').html('<h1>My Grocery List.</h1>');
        $('#change-look').click(function() {
            $('#grocery-list').css('color','blue');
            $('h1').css('font-weight','bold','font-variant','small-caps','text-decoration','underline');
        });
        $('#change-look').not(this).find('a').removeAttr('href');

});
```

And you should be ready to go. You can check out this [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xq7Z/1/)

Comment: That worked, but how come the (document).ready(function() wouldn't work? All of my examples in my books have it. Also do you know how I can remove the "Change my Look" linked after it's been clicked?

Comment: @jake: beacuse you are missing $ sign

Answer (score 1):

Function spelling is wrong in your code

```
$('#change-look').click(function() {
```

try correcting that first.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your code

`one` is pointed out by Era,
Function spelling is wrong in your code
change it

```
$('#change-look').click(function() {
```

`second` is

change `(document).ready(function() {`

(missing `$` sign)

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

From http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

```
>Basic syntax is: $(selector).action()
>A $ sign to define/access jQuery 
>A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements 
>A jQuery action() to be performed on the element(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others had mentioned, the `groceries` string that you take as the user's input to push to the array should be wrapped in `<li>` tags as it is within an unordered list, `<ol></ol>`. It would be invalid HTML to do otherwise.

Also, for your link, if you wanted to remove the 'href' attribute AFTER you click, you would need to put this line:

`$('#change-look').removeAttr('href');`

instead of:

`$('#change-look').not(this).find('a').removeAttr('href');`

**inside** of the click event, not outside. If you want to remove it entirely after the click, you can use:

`$('#change-look').remove();`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kaizora/YcqdZ/

Comment: $('#change-look').remove(); was exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.